# Complications while using EXCEPT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, except

I'm trying to select CustomerID that didn't ordered in year 1977 with:

```
SELECT CustomerID 
FROM orders
EXCEPT 
SELECT CustomerID 
FROM orders 
WHERE YEAR(OrderDate)=1977);
```

the table 'orders' contains both CustomerID and OrderDate

The error is:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT CustomerID FROM orders WHERE YEAR(OrderDate)=1977)' at line 1
```

Comment: I just reviewed the keywords in MySQL and I didn't see the `EXCEPT` syntax listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this::

```
SELECT CustomerID FROM orders WHERE YEAR(OrderDate)<>1977;
```